# Update row SQL in same table with data from other row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm stuck with making a SQL query to update different rows, all in the same table. But 1 row has to get data from another row which has the same reference ID (`bst__ref`).

**CURRENT TABLE `bstlyn__`**

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 157035 | 1/01/1980 | 2/04/2021 | 117210 | N | 0 | N |
| 157035 | 1/01/1980 | 25/03/2021 | 128078 | N | 0 | N |
| 157035 | 1/01/1980 | 25/03/2021 | 128078 | N | 0 | N |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 157036 | 1/01/1980 | 12/04/2021 | 117022 | N | 0 | N |
| 157036 | 1/01/1980 | 12/04/2021 | 117034 | N | 0 | N |
| 157036 | 1/01/1980 | 9/04/2021 | 128078 | N | 0 | N |

**CURRENT SQL QUERY**

```
UPDATE bstlyn__ SET G = 'Y', F = 'N', B = C WHERE E = 'N' AND F = '0'
```

This causes to change all `vrz__dat` lines to the same value as in `vrzv_dat`. But as you can see within the same `bst__ref`, the vrzv_dat of all `afg__ref`'s with value 128078 have a different `vrzv_dat`. This should be the same date/`vrz__dat` like the (first) row from that `bst__ref` which hasn't got `afg__ref` 128078.

So, after running the query above I get:

| bst__ref (A) | vrz__dat (B) | vrzv_dat (C) | afg__ref (D) | fiat____ (E) | fac__tst (F) | vrz__tst (G) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 157035 | 2/04/2021 | 2/04/2021 | 117210 | N | N | Y |
| 157035 | 25/03/2021 | 25/03/2021 | 128078 | N | N | Y |
| 157035 | 25/03/2021 | 25/03/2021 | 128078 | N | N | Y |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 157036 | 12/04/2021 | 12/04/2021 | 117022 | N | N | Y |
| 157036 | 12/04/2021 | 12/04/2021 | 117034 | N | N | Y |
| 157036 | 9/04/2021 | 9/04/2021 | 128078 | N | N | Y |

**But it should be:**

| bst__ref | vrz__dat | vrzv_dat | afg__ref | fiat____ | fac__tst | vrz__tst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 157035 | 2/04/2021 | *2/04/2021* | 117210 | N | N | Y |
| 157035 | **2/04/2021** | 25/03/2021 | 128078 | N | N | Y |
| 157035 | **2/04/2021** | 25/03/2021 | 128078 | N | N | Y |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 157036 | 12/04/2021 | *12/04/2021* | 117022 | N | N | Y |
| 157036 | 12/04/2021 | 12/04/2021 | 117034 | N | N | Y |
| 157036 | **12/04/2021** | 9/04/2021 | 128078 | N | N | Y |

How on Earth can I do this with only using SQL?
Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: FireDAC / Phys / ODBC / Microsoft / SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Comment: What defines "first row" how are you ordering them?

Comment: @Charlieface no Idea tbh, but normally the first row will never be with `afg__ref` 128078

Comment: If you can't define how we get the first row how can we solve this? Remember tables don't have inherent ordering, the results may come back different every time without explicit ordering

Answer (score 0):

You can use this  table twice, you just need to alias the table in the subqueries. Then perform retrieval only of the first for each same A code

try this code:

```
UPDATE bstlyn__ t, (SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C,D,E,F,G
                    FROM bstlyn__ ) t1
SET t.B = t1.C, G = 'Y', F = 'N'
WHERE t.A= t1.A
```

Comment: I tried `UPDATE bstlyn__
SET vrz__tst = 'Y',
 fac__tst = 'N',
 vrz__dat = (SELECT vrzv_dat
             FROM (SELECT TOP 1 vrzv_dat
                           FROM bstlyn__
                           ORDER BY bst__ref) t)
 WHERE fiat____ = 'N' AND fac__tst = '0'`
But then it takes the first one of the table (which has date 4/05/2012)

Comment: Some explanation of how your answer works would greatly approve this answer. The OP should be able to learn from this, not just copy/past and be glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate back to the same table. There are various ways of accomplishing this, you *appear* to want to do this specifcally on a single value, so if I have understood correctly you can try this

```
update b set 
vrz__tst = 'Y',
fac__tst = 'N',
vrz__dat = 
    case when afg_ref=128078 then 
        (select Min(vrzv_dat) from bstlyn__ b2 where b2.bst_ref=b.bst_ref)
    else vrzv_dat end
from  bstlyn__ b
where fiat____ = 'N' and fac__tst = '0'
```

Comment: Hm, in case you meant `Min(vrzv_dat)` then it's outputting the same as using my query. In case you meant `Min(vrz__dat)` then it's not changing any row which has `afg__ref`128078. It should change these also to the same `vrzv_dat` from 1 row which hasn't got `afg__ref` 128078 (but which share the same `bst__ref`). Difficult to explain, isn't it... :-)

Comment: Yes maybe I did mean that - tbh I have seen more easily readable queries. If would have been better, for a sample data example, for you to simply name the column A, B, C etc :)

Comment: Changed the column names in the upper table, hope it's a bit easier now to understand.
So; B has to become the same value as C, but when D has value '128078' it has to search the same rows of A and then pick the date from the first row (or a row which hasn't got '128078' in D) from column C and update it. So all rows from the same column A need to have the same value in column C

Comment: Aha! I think I've found it;
`update b set 
vrz__tst = 'Y',
fac__tst = 'N',
vrz__dat = 
    case when afg__ref='128078' then 
        (select Max(vrzv_dat) from bstlyn__ b2 where b2.bst__ref=b.bst__ref)
    else vrzv_dat end
from  bstlyn__ b
where fiat____ = 'N' and fac__tst = '0'
`
Of course in this scenario the date always has to be higher, but in my use-case that will (normally) always be like that.